# AWS EC2 Instance keeps disconnecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently, I'm using a Visual Studio Code SSH Plugin to edit my files directly on the EC2 without having to edit it locally and transfer the files. But I've noticed that the EC2 instance has stopped responding after 30 minutes or so and I have to keep rebooting the server in order for it to respond again. The problem is not with the plugin (in terms of connecting to the server) when VSC notifies me saying that the connection as dropped, the same thing occurred to all of my other SSH tools. Is there something I have to do in order for its connection to stay alive?

VSC Plugin: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Error:

```
[16:07:19.876] stderr> ssh: connect to host ec2Host port 22: Operation timed out
[16:07:19.877] > local-server> ssh child died, shutting down
[16:07:19.879] Local server exit: 0
[16:07:19.880] Received install output: OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
ssh: connect to host ec2Host port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: What os are you running on the ec2? And, is it an on-demand instance or a spot instance?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu and it's an on-demand instance I believe.

Comment: Are you doing anything that could be crashing the instance or locking the ssh-session out, using all the cpu or memory?

Comment: No not really, I just host small discord bots on there.

Comment: I basically do what you're doing all the time, and although it isn't perfect I haven't seen this issue. I do find that if I don't send anything over the connection for a while it'll try to disconnect and then lock up, and the same happens if I go get lunch and my machine sleeps, but this doesn't screw up the server -- though I do have to restart VSC.

Comment: Yeah, my CPU spikes to 99% when this happens so I have to reboot since its non-responsive.